# Cannot get lightning-map in LWC to refresh

Tags: lightning-web-components, google-map, lightning-map

This works to display some accounts in a given zip code on a map, but after it has worked once, I cannot get it to change to another zip code when clicking "Search" again. Interestingly, if I enter no search criteria and invoke !this.zipCodeSearch, it DOES reset the map, and I can search again. How can I change it to simply rerender the map upon each new search? I have tried setting this.searchData = undefined at the beginning of the new search to no avail, and setting this.mapMarkers= [] at the beginning also does nothing, though I have seen others claim it worked for them.

HTML 

{errorMsg}

```
        <lightning-layout multiple-rows="true" vertical-align="end">
            <lightning-layout-item size="12" small-device-size="10" medium-device-size="8" large-device-size="6" padding="around-small">
                <div class="slds-form-element">
                        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                            <lightning-input type="text" 
                                                label="Enter Zip Code" 
                                                onchange={handleZipCodeSearch} ></lightning-input>
                        </div>
                </div> 
            </lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-layout-item size="12" small-device-size="2" medium-device-size="2" large-device-size="2" padding="around-small">
                <lightning-button label="Search" 
                                    variant="brand" 
                                    onclick={handleAccountSearch}>
                </lightning-button>
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout><br/>
        
        <div if:true={showmap}>
            <lightning-map
                map-markers={mapMarkers}
                markers-title={markersTitle} >
            </lightning-map>
        </div>
        
</lightning-card>
```

JS

```
    @track showmap = false;
    @track errorMsg = '';
    @track zipCodeSearch = '';
    @track limit = 10;
    @track mapMarkers = [];

    handleZipCodeSearch(event) {
        this.zipCodeSearch = event.detail.value;
    }

    handleAccountSearch() {
        this.showmap = false;
        this.mapMarkers= [];

        if(!this.zipCodeSearch) {
            this.errorMsg = 'Please enter zipcode to search accounts.';
            this.searchData = undefined;
            return;
        }

        let params = {};
            params.zipCode = this.zipCodeSearch;
            params.soqlLimit = this.limit;

        searchAccounts(params)
        .then(result => {               
            result.forEach((accRecord) => {
                console.dir('>>>>> Found account '+JSON.stringify(accRecord));
                
                var marker = {
                    value: accRecord.Id,
                    location: {
                        accRecord etc...
                    },                              
                    icon: 'standard:account',                        
                }; 
                
            this.mapMarkers.push(marker);               
            });
                
            console.dir('>>>>> mapMarkers '+JSON.stringify(this.mapMarkers));

            this.showmap = true;
            this.error = undefined;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.searchData = undefined;
                window.console.log('error =====> '+JSON.stringify(error));
            if(error) {
                window.console.log('>>>>> ERROR '+ error);
            }
        })
    }
    @track markersTitle = "Accounts Found";
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a decent solution and updated the code in the OP - the only way to refresh the map seemed to be hide it and then show it again using a condition in the HTML. Toggling this.showmap from false to true in the handleAccountSearch method nicely gives the appearance of the map refreshing itself and then showing the updated markers.